# Difference of two random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

$X\,$ follows exponential $1$ and $Y$ follws Gamma distribution with mean $2$  and variance $2$.Given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent What is $P(X\lt Y)=??$
What i did was first i found the distribution of $X-Y$ by using a transformation as $X=U+V\;and\; Y=V$ by using this i got the joint pdf of $U$ and $V$ and then i found the pdf of $U$ by integrating over V. But i got the pdf as $$f_U (u)={e^u (1-2u)}/{4}\;when\; -\infty\lt u\lt 0$$ and $$e^{-u}/4\; when\; u\gt 0$$.but this doesnt seem to be the pdf because it integrates to $0$.please if somebody can help me??
I am.also getting $P (U\lt 0)=-(1/4)$
$f_U (u)=\int_{-u}^{\infty}e^{-u}ve^{-2v}dv$ when $-\infty\lt u\lt 0\;$
$f_U (u)=\int_0^\infty e^{-u}ve^{-2v}dv$ when $0\lt u\lt \infty $
This is how i got $f_U$

Comment: Hmmm... *The Way of the (Mathematician) is one of immediacy, and it is best to dash in headlong*, as they (almost) say, so... $$P(X<Y)=\int_0^\infty\left(\int_0^yf_X(x)\,dx\right)\,f_Y(y)\,dy.$$

Comment: I understand this but i just wanted to know what is wrong in my method..is this wrong?? $did$

Comment: Right, but since you do not show how you reached the density $f_U$, this is difficult to know.

Comment: I have written how i got$ f_U $

Comment: Why do you think the integral of $f_U$ is zero? Note that $f_U>0$ everywhere...

Comment: Because when i calculated $P(U\lt 0)= -1/4$

Comment: Probabilities are never negative....

Comment: Yes that is what i am not able yo understand why is it coming wrong

Comment: $$P(U<0)=\int_{-\infty}^0f_U(u)\,du=\int_{-\infty}^0e^u\tfrac14(1-2u)\,du={}{}{}{}{}{}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-u}\tfrac14(1+2u)\,du=+\tfrac34$$

Comment: And no idea whatsoever where the identity $$P(U<0)=-\tfrac14f_U(u)$$ is coming from...

Comment: Thnx Did i got my mistake